# What can I do when the reset password function isn't working?

Tags: passwords

I have a CiviCRM account. I've forgotten my login and password. I tried to use the reset password feature and entered the email address associated with my account. I didn't get an email to reset the password though. In Outlook, I've checked the junk folder and the "other"  tab of the inbox, as well as doing a search of my entire email, but can't find an email from CiviCRM. Is there another way I can resent my password or get help with logging in?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE!

I'm guessing you are talking about an account on your organisation's CiviCRM system.  If the password reset link is not working you will need to contact the administrators of that system.

Or do you mean you are the admin and have lost access?

Alternatively do you mean an account on civicrm.org?

Or maybe an account on [CiviCRM Spark](https://civicrm.com/)?